# Python else vs unindent

Tags: python-3.x

Say there is a code with a conditional `if` and `else`. I noticed that often, instead of writing `else` at the end of the code, you can unindent it, which makes it slightly more elegant and saves at least one line. For example:

```
def letter_check(word, letter):
  if word in letter:
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

vs

```
def letter_check(word, letter):
  if word in letter:
    return True
  return False
```

Those two codes would output the same result. Can you give me an instance, where `else` would make a difference or would be advantageous? And I am not talking about `elif`. 
Thanks

Comment: I find the first snippet more explicit. I guess that's why I actually find it more elegant as well than the second snippet. Having said that, I don't think there is functional different in this case

Comment: Replace `return ...` in the `if` branch by anything that doesn't return/throw/otherwise leave the function.

Comment: Note that the entire function body should just be ``return word in letter`` here. Dropping a measly ``else`` is a red herring.

Answer (score 1):

There's no matter with `return` statement, because `return` exits from function, but if you want to do something else, it can be different:

```
def letter_check(word, letter):
  if word in letter:
    print "1"
  else:
    print "2"

--> 1  # if true      
--> 2  # if false

def letter_check(word, letter):
  if word in letter:
    print "1"
  print "2"

--> 1 --> 2 # if true       
--> 2  # if false
```

Comment: What do you mean by -- > 1 --> 2? From what I understand, the second function will always output "2". However, after checking the code, the output will be "1" if the condition is True.

Comment: This means that it outputs 1 then 2, i.e. both print functions called `if word in letter`

Answer (score -1):

A common practice is to return the result of a function at the end of the body of such function. In this case, a `result` variable is used and returned at the end of the function.

Edit: I will change the original example of the question in my answer since the `True/False` pattern does not help to understand.

```
def compute_word_len(word, with_digits=False):
  """ Return the size of the given word with or without
  the digits according to the with_digits parameter.
  """
  if with_digits:
    result = len(word)
  else:
    result = len(''.join([c for c in word if not c.isdigit()]))
  return result
```

If the `if/else` block is binary, the variable can then be initialized by a default value and changed in the `if` block. This case is useful only if the function to compute the default value is not time consuming.

```
def compute_word_len(word, with_digits=False):
  """ Return the size of the given word with or without
  the digits according to the with_digits parameter.
  """
  result = len(word)
  if not with_digits:
    result = len(''.join([c for c in word if not c.isdigit()]))
  return result
```

Another practice is to get rid of the cases where the function should just not be run. This can avoid to write the body of the function in an unnecessary indented `if` block:

```
def compute_word_len(word, with_digits=False):
  """ Return the size of the given word with or without
  the digits according to the with_digits parameter.
  """
  if not word:
    return 0

  result = len(word)
  if not with_digits:
    result = len(''.join([c for c in word if not c.isdigit()]))
  return result
```

Comment: Yes I hesitated to say that the given example was not very accurate relatively to the question. I shall edit my answer.

Comment: Note that computing the non-digit length would be more efficient via ``sum(1 for c in word if not c.isdigit())``. The current version needlessly creates a full list and string in-memory.

Answer (score -1):

There is a slight difference in the OP-codes of the two functions:

```py
def without_else(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 0
    return 1

def with_else(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1

import dis

print(" --- Without else --- ")
dis.dis(without_else)

print(" --- With else --- ")
dis.dis(with_else)
```

***Without else:***

```
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              4 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
              6 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       12

  3           8 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
             10 RETURN_VALUE

  4     >>   12 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             14 RETURN_VALUE
```

***With else:***

```
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              4 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
              6 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       12

  3           8 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
             10 RETURN_VALUE

  5     >>   12 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             14 RETURN_VALUE
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)  # This is the implicit return
             18 RETURN_VALUE                       # None added by python
```

Notice that from instructions 0-14, **both functions give the exact same op-codes**. The only difference is there is an *implicit* `return None` added to the end of the `with_else` function. This is not likely to impact performance in *any* way (despite the **extreeeeemely** small overhead required for compiling the implicit `return None`).

Personally, I prefer to use `without_else` when I can; I think it looks nicer.